# Mathematical Induction: Why don't we just substitute $n$ by $(n+1)$?

Tags: induction, axioms

Step 2 of *proof by mathematical induction* is to show that if a formula is true for any positive integer $n\geq n_{0}$, then it is also true for $(n+1)$. To proof the formula for “the sum of the first $n$ positive integers,” we add $(n+1)$ to both sides of the equation $1+2+3+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. We multiply the binomial expansion equation for $(a+x)^n$ by $(a+x)$ to show that it is also true for $(a+x)^{n+1}$.

Why don't we just substitute $n$ by $(n+1)$ instead? It's definitely easier that way. I know it's incorrect to do so, since we don't do that; but ***why*** is it an incorrect thing to do?

Comment: Because you don't know the statement is true for $n+1$. That's what you want to show. If you could just substitute anything in for anything else when trying to prove something, you could prove anything you wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only valid to substitute $n+1$ for $n$ if you know that $p(n)$ being true implies that $p(n+1)$ is true; but proving $p(n) \Rightarrow p(n+1)$ is exactly what you need to do in the induction step!

You can certainly substitute $n+1$ for $n$ to figure out what it is you need to work towards in the induction step, but you can't just make the substitution and say you're finished.

Comment: I get it now, it just doesn't work that way. BTW I had another question, but not really a lengthy one. Should I ask it here, or should I edit my post and add it up?

Comment: @AmandaMacaurenni: It's usually best to just create a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)—short questions are just as welcome as long ones on MSE. Or if your question is a follow-up to my answer, here is fine.

Comment: Will do that, then.